# Java common ForkJoinPool parallelism

Tags: java, multithreading, fork-join, forkjoinpool

If I run the following code:

```
System.out.println("Common Pool Parallelism: "
        +ForkJoinPool.getCommonPoolParallelism());

long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

IntStream.range(0, ForkJoinPool.getCommonPoolParallelism() * 2)
    .parallel()
    .forEach(i -> {
        System.out.println(i +" " +(System.currentTimeMillis() - start) +"ms");
        LockSupport.parkNanos(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toNanos(1));
    });
```

I get (for example) the following output:

```
Common Pool Parallelism: 3
5 82ms
3 82ms
1 82ms
0 82ms
4 1087ms
2 1087ms
```

It appears to me as though the common ForkJoinPool is using 4 threads, then they're blocked for a second, then the last two jobs are run.

But as I understand it, the common ForkJoinPool defaults to using Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() - 1 threads, which in my case is 3 so I'd expect to get three jobs printing at ~82ms not 4.

Is it my code or or understanding that's amiss?

ETA: Printing out Thread.currentThread().getId() within the forEach also shows 4 different thread IDs.

Comment: The FJ framework uses the submitting thread (your main()) as a worker. It may also create additional threads when worker threads block.

Answer (score 0):

The extra thread in your output is main thread.
You can check via printing thread name using Thread.currentThread().getName()

```
  System.out.println("Common Pool Parallelism: "
            +ForkJoinPool.getCommonPoolParallelism());

    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

    IntStream.range(0, ForkJoinPool.getCommonPoolParallelism() * 2)
            .parallel()
            .forEach(i -> {
                System.out.println(i +" "+Thread.currentThread().getName()+" "+" " +(System.currentTimeMillis() - start) +"ms");
                LockSupport.parkNanos(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toNanos(1));
            });
```